# Threading or multiprocess to run code in parallel seems slower

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I've been searching with little success how to solve this problem. The script below is supposed to perform planet simulations. planet1_pars will define 1st planet parameters. set_grids_fakePlanet will create a grid for each of the parameters of a hypothetical planet put into the system. This function will return a generator not a list/array with tons of parameter values. planet2_pars will give me a set of parameters previously created in set_grids_fakePlanet, hence each time I execute planet2_pars it will give me a different set of parameters from the hypothetical planet. ComputeTTV will do some calculations and return what I need each time I execute run_rebound, which is my main function that will call all these mentioned functions above. Whenever I execute run_rebound, I need to give it the hypothetical planet parameter so it run the simulation.

```
def planet1_pars():
    P_p1,m_p1,e_p1 = 0.7920639164 / 365.25, 29.32*3.0027e-6, 0.0 #P[yrs], m[solar],e[fixed]
    inc_p1,omega_p1,M_p1 = 77.4041697839 * np.pi/180, 90., 0.
    return P_p1,m_p1,e_p1,inc_p1,omega_p1,M_p1 

def set_grids_fakePlanet(pars_p1):
    P_p1,m_p1,e_p1,inc_p1,omega_p1,M_p1 = [*pars_p1]
    
    #min max periods in which to put a planet
    Pmin = P_p1 * 2.02 # Pmin ~ 0.0196/365.25 #shortest period found so far in exoplanet.eu
    Pmax = P_p1 * 2.05
    #set grids
    P_grid = np.arange(Pmin, Pmax, P_p1 * 0.005)
    m_p2_grid = np.arange(.5, 320, 1) * 3.0027e-6 # every 1 Earth mass to 1 Jupiter
    e_grid = [0.0]#np.linspace(0,0.1, 10) # e=1 may cause code to blow up
    inc_grid = [inc_p1]#np.linspace(60,90, 5)
    omega_grid = [0.0]#np.linspace(0,360, 5)
    M_grid = [0.0]#np.linspace(0,360, 5)

    #store grid vals, each column is a parameter, last column TTV amplitude
    #[n,m] n is max_size(P,e,inc,omega,M) ** m.  m is # of orbital parameters + 1 ttv amp
    size = len(P_grid) * len(m_p2_grid) * len(e_grid) * len(inc_grid) * len(omega_grid) * len(M_grid)
    results = np.zeros([size,6+1]) * np.nan  

    peiom_grid = ((x,k,y,w,j,z) for x in P_grid for k in m_p2_grid for y in e_grid for w in inc_grid
                  for j in omega_grid  for z in M_grid)
    return peiom_grid

def planet2_pars():
    for pars_p2 in peiom_grid:
        return pars_p2
        
    #2nd planet
#     m_p2, P_p2, e_p2, inc_p2, omega_p2, M_p2 = system_parameters(n*m_p1, P_p2,e_p2,inc_p2,omega_p2,M_p2)


def computeTTVs(sim, P_p1, P_p2):
    N=34
    transittimes = np.zeros(int(N))
    p = sim.particles
    i = 0
    while i<N:
        y_old = p[1].y - p[0].y  # (Thanks to David Martin for pointing out a bug in this line!)
        t_old = sim.t
        if P_p1 > P_p2:
            sim.integrate(sim.t+ (P_p2 * 0.05)) # check for transits every 0.5 time units. Note that 0.5 is shorter than one orbit
        else:
            sim.integrate(sim.t+ (P_p1 * 0.05)) #5% of period ~ 1h which is shorter than Tdur=2h
            
        t_new = sim.t
        if y_old*(p[1].y-p[0].y)<0. and p[1].x-p[0].x>0.:   # sign changed (y_old*y<0), planet in front of star (x>0)
            while t_new-t_old>1e-7:   # bisect until prec of 1e-5 reached
                if y_old*(p[1].y-p[0].y)<0.:
                    t_new = sim.t
                else:
                    t_old = sim.t
                sim.integrate( (t_new+t_old)/2.)
            transittimes[i] = sim.t
            i += 1
            sim.integrate(sim.t+ P_p1 * 0.01)       # integrate 0.05 to be past the transit

    A = np.vstack([np.ones(N), range(N)]).T
    c, m = np.linalg.lstsq(A, transittimes, rcond=-1)[0] # fits a linear model and get period m and t0 c
    comp_t0s = c + m*np.array(range(N)) 

    OC = transittimes-comp_t0s # in years
    OC *= 365.25*24*60
    amp = rms(OC)
#     amp = np.diff([np.min(OC), np.max(OC)])[0]
    return amp #in minutes

def run_rebound(pars_p2):
    ms=1.02 #solar unit
    P_p1,m_p1,e_p1,inc_p1,omega_p1,M_p1 = planet1_pars()
    P_p2,m_p2,e_p2,inc_p2,omega_p2,M_p2 = [*pars_p2] #fake planet
    #start simulation
    sim = rebound.Simulation()
    sim.G = 39.478 #AU^3 yr^-2 Ms^-1
    sim.add(m=ms)
    sim.add(m=m_p1, P=P_p1, e=e_p1, inc=inc_p1, omega=omega_p1, M=M_p1)
    sim.add(m=m_p2, P=P_p2, e=e_p2, inc=inc_p2, omega=omega_p2, M=M_p2)
    #put outcomes in a list
    results = [P_p2,m_p2,e_p2,inc_p2*(180/np.pi),omega_p2,M_p2, computeTTVs(sim, P_p1, P_p2)] 
    return results
```

Question: I tried to make it parallel using the threading library as in:

```
peiom_grid = set_grids_fakePlanet(planet1_pars()) #make the fake planet grid as a generator variable

import threading

start = time.time()
for pars in peiom_grid:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_rebound, args=(pars,))
    
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

    
end = time.time()

print((end-start) /60, 'min')
```

In this manner, I see the 8 CPU I got is being used but at a rate which is less than 50%.
And it takes ~ 1.2 min to run (the grids are small because I am testing, but ideally the grids should be lager so it may take days to run).

I also tried MultiProcessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process
start = time.time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for pars in peiom_grid:
        
        p = Process(target=run_rebound, args=(pars,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        
end = time.time()
print((end-start) /60, 'min')
```

it takes ~ 1.7min

and without any parallelization

```
start = time.time()

for pars in peiom_grid:
    run_rebound(pars)

end = time.time()
print((end-start)/60, 'min')
```

it takes ~ 1.34 min

I think I am not doing any parallelization because the difference between the runs above with/without parallelization isn't significant. I cannot find where the issue is. I followed a few examples and check several examples on stack overflow but nothing... Hope you guys can give me some feedback.

Comment: Python isn't terribly good at multithreading because too many of its operations rely on the GIL or Global Interpreter Lock.  Effectively only one thread at a time gets to execute.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Note: If the OP were using `numpy` well, with large arrays, the GIL would be less of a problem; `numpy` releases the GIL when performing operations on sufficiently large arrays of primitives. It does look like a lot of the code here is not using `numpy` optimally (there's an array or two, but mostly it's doing Python level work with Python level types), so the point about the GIL stands.

Comment: Multithreading is no help for cpu-intensive tasks, it just adds overhead.  Multiprocessing will only help if you can take advantage of multiple core hardware so you literally have multiple processors (not processes) running in parallel.    Multithreading typically helps only when you have i/o bound processes running as well.

Comment: @RufusVS, Multithreading _in Python_ is no help...  Multithreading in most other programming languages _can_ be used for parallel computation. Python is a special case because of the GIL. That was a design decision that the author made back when typical workstation computers had only one CPU core, and because it affects the language semantics, we're basically stuck with it. Newer languages don't have anything like the GIL. Nor do older languages with simpler run-time support libraries that don't need to be thread-aware.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Multithreading in ANY language is no help for CPU intensive tasks on a system with only one core.  For computational tasks, all it does is add overhead for context switches to share the processor.  Independent of Python's GIL.

Comment: @RufusVS, Yes, that is absolutely true. But apart from embedded microcontrollers these days, where can you find a computer system that has only one core? Modern workstations, laptops, servers, tablets, and smart phones pretty much all have multiple CPU cores.

Answer (score 4):

In case of multithreading - Mark is right, the bottleneck is Python GIL. However, multiprocessing is free of this limitation (but is subject to a different overhead, minimal in this case).

The reason you don't see any improvement is because `.join()` waits for process execution. So, this implementation starts a single process and then immediately blocks until it is complete. To fix this, move `.join()` out of the process creation loop:

```
processes = []
for pars in peiom_grid:
    p = Process(target=run_rebound, args=(pars,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

A more straightforward way to do this would be to use process pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as pool:  # will use the number of CPUs in the system by default
    results = pool.map(run_rebound, peiom_grid)
```

Comment: Thank you @Marat and everyone that took the time to help me out. Although I know the 'basics' of python, I couldn't figure that out myself. Really appreciate the effort and the discussions. Marat that piece of code made the runs go from 1.7 min to 0.39 minutes, I am baffled! That is exactly what I needed. What I still need though is to get a better grasp on what you all are talking about in the discussion below my question. For now, that answer simply solved my problems! again, thanks Marat!